# Can I add accelerators to enter a date in a Angular Material Datepicker field?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I am working on a web application using Angular. Is there a way to add shortcuts/accelerators to the date input? For example, a user should be able to type "+1" and have the input resolve to tomorrow's date. At the very least I would like to be able to set an input of "6-18" to 6-18-2020 instead of 6-18-2001.

I am using Angular 9 and Material 8.

Comment: Hi!, it would be useful to help you if you could provide a code snippet or even better, a jsfiddle example of the code that is not working. That helps people try out solutions and by the end they will be able to provide you a working example of what you want to achieve.
Also be sure to share which version of Angular and Angular Material are you usuing because it can condition the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved this in case anyone else has the same issue. This enables dates to be entered via +1 (tomorrow), -1 (yesterday), etc.

I created a directive...

```
 export class DateEntryShortcutsDirective {
// form control bound to datepicker input
  @Input() control: FormControl;

  constructor() {}

// listen for change events on the datepicker input
  @HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange(event: any) {
    this.setDate(event.target.value);
  }

  setDate(data) {
    if (typeof data === 'string' && data.length) {
// if values begins with '+' 
      if (data.substring(0, 1) === '+') {
// get current date and advance by however many days requested
        const dayDiff = +data.substring(1);
        const date = new Date(
          new Date().getTime() + dayDiff * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        );
// set the control value to date 
        if (this.control) {
          this.control.setValue(date);
        }
      } else if (data.substring(0, 1) === '-') {
// if value begins with '-'
// get current day and subtract days 
        const dayDiff = +data.substring(1);
        const date = new Date(
          new Date().getTime() - dayDiff * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        );
// set control to date
        if (this.control) {
          this.control.setValue(date);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The directive is then used like so...

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-form-field date items">
    <mat-label>Deliver NLT</mat-label>
    <input
      tabindex="{{ 80 + index * 1500 }}"
      matInput
      autocomplete="off"
      [matDatepicker]="receiverNLTDate"
      placeholder="Date NLT"
      formControlName="receiverNoLaterThanDate"
      (dateChange)="onReceiverNoLaterThanChanges()"
      [min]="
        this.data.reference.freightUnits[this.index]
          .receiverRequestedDeliveryDate
      "
      appDateEntryShortcuts
      [control]="receiverNoLaterThanDate"
      />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matSuffix
      [for]="receiverNLTDate"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #receiverNLTDate></mat-datepicker>
```

**EDIT**

After gaining some more understanding, I now extend `Native Date Adapter` and override its parse function with my own.